# When it comes to creating organic "machines", which method would be best?

Tags: biology, creature-design

If it became possible to intentionally direct the growth of organic material such as woods, muscles or bones, allowing for creation of organic structure,
which method would be more economical in overall production, designing and performance? And by economical, I mean that would it be able to compete or even prove superior to current technological method?

would it be more economical to simply create traditional machines like cars or plane using organic materials, such as ?
or would creation of artificial beast of burden for specific performance be more economical?
or maybe it would be best to just use organic materials to supplement existing technology, such as adding bio-luminescent lamp or self-sealing rubber tire to mechanical car?

The first solution would probably be more easier to design but inferior in performance, while second solution would probably be opposite.
however, would difficulty of designing such complex creature outweigh benefit of performance?

What do you think?

*I'm not a native speaker, so if you find any grammatical error, please do tell me so I can improve my English!

Comment: What is the criteria to measure "best?" or "efficient?"

Comment: @user535733 Efficiency is usually the least effort to achieve the most outcome. The criteria depend on matter under consideration. The word 'best' doesn't appear in the question. You may measure by whatever criteria you prefer.

Comment: The development of organic machines will occur when this type of technology is most useful, economic or suitable for the task. It may be used in art projects rather than general utility technology.

Comment: @a4android "best" is in the title. It's not clear if "efficient" refers to cost, effort, time, or another comparative factor. I think most "efficient" is to plant one seed and wait 40 years...but it's unclear if the OP shares my view.

Comment: @user535733 So it does. The problem is that criteria measurement of either efficiency or bestness doesn't help the OP improve their question. Like many querents, especially ESL ones, the OP has had difficulty finding how to express what they want to achieve succinctly. A nifty idea at its heart, but not the most practical.

Comment: The question is clearer after edits, but I think it is still primarily opinion based. I would leave it closed, but I’m willing to be convinced by other reviewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Organic material is very fragile.**
Especially when compared to our modern machines and their functions, organic material with bone structures will be too fragile. There is a reason we moved on from using horses for example, as even selective breeding of them couldn't keep up with the development of cars. Steel structures are simply stronger than bone and muscle, and will withstand more extreme situations.

**They will be outperformed by technology.**
The fastest bird (the peregrine falcon) can reach 360kmh (200mph) in dive, and needs to be extremely streamlined and  gravity assisted to do so. A simple air plane or chopper can easily be on par with this performance, on top of being able to carry amounts of passengers and/or cargo.

**Maintenance/repairs.**
One of your biggest concerns when replacing a piece of technology with organic material. Sure, if an organism gets damaged, it can often repair itself. A car that will literally heal the scratches after you hit a pole sounds like a very handy and novelty item. However, the time this takes needs to be considered. If I popped a wheel on my car, all I need to do to replace it is take it off and fit another. If an organic car breaks a wheel, either it can't be repaired, or will take several days if not weeks to heal, and your car will be out of commission for the duration. This is why often historically when a horse developed a limp, instead of taking the time to heal it, it was killed to save the effort and spare it the suffering.

**Control.**
When controlling a car, plane, drone, or any human operated machine, you can reasonably expect it to do precisely as you operate it. It will not flinch when getting too close to a hazard, it will not scream in pain when such a hazard is hit. Any living creature will have an averse effect to control precision, especially if it has any mind of its own. Adding to this, strain and fatigue will influence this as well.

Based on this consideration, I don't think it's very likely that organic machines will ever be developed for anything but a novelty item. However, I don't mean to say this isn't already being done:

[image: Living tree houses by Patrick Dougherty]

Not exactly a machine, but if organic structures have any future at all, this will be it. A friend of mine is very active in development of organic tree houses and structures, and it is looking more plausible by the day. Things like short bridges and fences are easily created, and even living furniture is possible. Living houses will repair themselves, and provide an extremely carbon-neutral and climate considerate form of housing. Of course these have massive downsides by way of quality of life, but this is being developed and might be fairly plausible in the future.

Comment: I agree with all of your arguments but not necessarily the conclusions - self-repair (even if slow) could become a huge upside in environments that are not (well) accessible. Think of space exploration or remote colonies - anything that needs to last for years (at least) and can't be accessed during that time.

Comment: @Nicolai, yes, when an area cannot be accessed for a long time then self-repair could be favourable. However in that case you could run into the issue of fuel/food supply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Perhaps integrating some part of organic technology but not all of them might be the most practical solution.

Answer (score 3):

So, in a way, we already use organic machines to do work for us. However, it is on a much smaller scale than cars and planes. Lots of modern medical research can be boiled down to “reprogramming” viruses and bacteria to do what we want them to do. A lot of the stuff involving retroviruses is especially interesting in this regard.

In regards to your macro-scale bioengineering, the answer is... well its complicated. Like the other answer said, machinery is easy to modify, simple to repair, and has no mind of its own so it does exactly what you tell it to do, exactly when you tell it to do it.

Good news though! Large scale bioengineered “vehicles” can be justified in specific situations. For example, we have various vehicles that are excellent at climbing rough terrain, nature has a goat. Having owned multiple goats I can confidently say that gravity is more of a suggestion to them, not a law. The most important thing to remember, is that if your vehicles are essentially animals, then they will have to be treated like a beast of burden and not a car or plane.

As for your other method, I think the most likely scenario is not that you build an organic vehicle, but rather you use some type of bioengineered microscopic organism that secretes an exceptionally tough, lightweight material to build the body of your vehicles, and then you add the necessary components; wires, engines, and glass. This means you can have an organic car, but not a living one. For bonus points, if you can sufficiently control said microorganisms, you can have them live inside the frame of the vehicles, allowing them to heal any damage over a relatively short period of time. Also, depending on how advanced your technology is, you may even be able to design “engines” and “batteries” that use similar microorganisms to produce large amounts of energy to power your vehicle. For some extra inspiration, look at corals, which are animals that excel and building a tough, non-living shell, the osteoblasts in your own body, which secrete the inorganic matrix that gives your bones their strength, and various extremophile bacteria/archaea, which excel at using extreme environments to produce energy.

Comment: Thank you for answering! And I liked how you elaborated on "beast of burden" idea. That was exact word that I was looking for.